# In ClojureScript Reagent, how can I register an event handler that captures the capturing events?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm using ClojureScript Reagent and I would like to capture an event during the capturing phase.

I read the React.js document and found that I can register the event handler in the way like `onClickCapture` so I hope this could work if I add `:on-click-capture` in my Reagent code:

```
[:tr {:on-click-capture (fn [e] (.log js/console (.-eventPhase e)))}]
```

The output is always 3 which is bubbling phase. How can I make it work for capturing events?

Comment: First, i want to point your attention to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3729 may be it is related to your problem. Second thing is that despite if `eventPhase == 3`, `:on-click-capture` triggers before `:on-click`. You can also do `(.stopPropagation e)` in `:on-click-capture`, which would cancel `:on-click`